# JQuery wont load in any browser other then Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I was trying a little loading bar but my JQuery doesn't load when I try this in FireFox & Chrome, it only loads on Safari.
this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mijn eerste spel</title>
<link href="opmaak.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="knop">
    <div id="textknop">Gooi Steen</div>
    <div id="laadbalk"></div>
</div>
<h1 id="money">$0</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and my jq code is:

```
$(Document).ready(function(){
 alert("test")
});
```

In Safari it produces the popup but any other browser just ignores my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, just change `Document` to `document` in javascript code.

Comment: Wow man, thank you very much. this is a pretty stupid mistake